# Get messageID from pdus object

Tags: android

My app listens to new sms'n. Now When I receive a new one I create a SmsMessage. For doing further operations on this, I need the Id of the message. So I query the content resolver like this:

```
 final Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();

    try {

        if (bundle != null) {
            //get the protocol discription unit ( SMSs)
            final Object[] pdusObj = (Object[]) bundle.get("pdus");

            for (int i = 0; i < pdusObj.length; i++) {

                SmsMessage currentMessage = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[]) pdusObj[i]);
                String phoneNumber = currentMessage.getDisplayOriginatingAddress();
                String message = currentMessage.getDisplayMessageBody();
                long time_rcv = currentMessage.getTimestampMillis();

                String [] relevantColumns = {"_id", "address", "body", "date_sent"};
                Cursor cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(
                        Uri.parse("content://sms/inbox"),
                        relevantColumns,
                        "address = '" + phoneNumber + "' AND body = '" + message
                                + "' AND date_sent = '" + time_rcv + "'",
                        null,
                        null);

                if (cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                    int id = Integer.valueOf(cursor.getString(0));
                    Log.d(TAG,"ID SMS: " + id);
                }
                else
                    Log.e(TAG,"Failed to find ID");

                Log.i(TAG, "FROM: " + phoneNumber + "; MSG: " + message);

                Toast.makeText(context, "From: " + phoneNumber + ", MSG: " + message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Exception receiver" + e);

    }
```

Whatever happens it never finds the message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My code was correct. The only problem is, that the sms isn't in the sms/inbox until my receivebroadcast is finished. So the next time you run the code and fill the fields manually the code finds the sms and gives you the id.